# Pound symbol issue in mailto: link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, encoding, mailto

In my ASP.NET MVC application I am creating a `mailto` link where the subject and body contain a pound £ symbol.

This appears to work in most cases but some users with Outlook 2003/Chrome is reporting that when clicking the link the pound symbol is showing as  `Â£`, which looks to me like it is interpreting a UTF-8 string as ascii/windows-1252/whatever etc.

I'm not sure how I should encode this. Currently I am using the following:

```
public static HtmlString EncodeMailTo(this HtmlHelper hlp, string val)
{
  var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val).Replace("+", "%20");
  return new HtmlString(encoded);
}
```

and in the view:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=@(Html.EncodeMailTo(Model.Offer.Heading))&body=@(Html.EncodeMailTo(Model.Offer.Requirement))" >
    Link
</a>
```

Is there a way that I can convert this to a different encoding (e.g. Windows-1252) before UrlEncoding it? I've tried converting the encoding of the string and then passing this and the encoding used into UrlEncode but get ? instead of the £ symbols then.

Comment: `mailto:?subject=You have won &pound;500!` works for me with Chrome/Thunderbird, can't test other combos right now but maybe worth a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to find any one answer that solves this problem for all browsers/email clients. Using the `&pound;` as suggested by [Matt Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751760/pound-symbol-issue-in-mailto-link/7751818#7751818) may work on some clients in this instance. However, you'll run in to problems with other characters that do not have a named html entity, or browsers/email clients that do not handle entities correctly.

Even more annoying is if you correct it for one browser/email set up (e.g. using Windows-1252) it might then break clients using UTF-8.

In the end, the only real solution is for browsers and email clients to upgrade to using UTF-8, see [Avoiding an international mailto maelstrom](http://www.siao2.com/2007/07/21/3993622.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try deliberately encoding as `&pound;`

```
public static HtmlString EncodeMailTo(this HtmlHelper hlp, string val)
{
  var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val).Replace("+", "%20").Replace("%C2%A3", "&pound;");

  return new HtmlString(encoded);
}
```

The £ symbol is not part of the basic ASCII character set.  So ASCII will not interpret it correctly.

Comment: I will try this. However your code won't work as is because the £ symbol will already be encoded by the time your `Replace()` runs

Comment: Sorry - try replacing "£" with "%C2%A3" (The URL encoded £ symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Enhancement on Matt Fellow's answer +1

```
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(val));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get stuff like `saving+of+a+minimum+of+&#163;5.99` when clicking the link